# Enterprise manager configuration error during installation

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

I am installing Oracle Database 11G on Windows 10 64-bit. I am getting this error:

[image]

Please help. How to solve this problem?

Note I am installing in Administrator account.

Comment: This post might help: http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2012/08/23/whats-oracle_unqname/

Answer (score 0):

These warnings are normal in Windows. The link that @vercelli posted spells it out, but I will paraphrase the important parts here for people that are weary of clicking the link:

1. > The ORACLE_UNQNAME is an operating system environment variable that
   >   holds the database’s unique name value. You can find it with the
   >   following query as the SYSTEM user (through SQL*Plus): `SELECT name, db_unique_name FROM v$database;`

and

2. > ORACLE_UNQNAME is not set as a Windows environment variable by default. You need to do this manually. There are actually two
   >   environment values you need to set. They are: %ORACLE_HOSTNAME% and
   >   %ORACLE_UNQNAME%.

All credit due to maclochlainn, who appears to be the author of the blog post.